# Test API Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, api

I have this code that i have got from the official tutorial on facebook

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root">sei qui</div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '173721946132851',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//www.ilmiobloggo.net/LOVECALCULATOR/index.php', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

But FB.api not working and i don't understand why, someoune can i help me. I have try to obtain the Apache log error to my house hosting, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing

```
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
  });
```

under the line that says

```
  // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
```

but above the

```
  };
```

e.g

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : '173721946132851',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
  channelUrl : '//www.ilmiobloggo.net/LOVECALCULATOR/index.php', // Channel file for x-domain comms
  status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});
};
```

You're calling FB.api before FB is created. Also this would produce JavaScript errors which would be found in your browser. Not in the Apache logs. Try opening up Chrome Developer tools/firebug etc. and viewing the console.

One final note, you don't have any code for a user to [authorize](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) your app. Unless the user has granted permissions to access your account, FB.api('/me') won't return you a correct response as it needs a user access token

Comment: I have done it , thanks for this, but now i obtain  with this code that the name is undefined i already try it , also the addons of Fireforx, but nothing,some ideas?

Comment: Have you granted you app permission like I say in my last paragraph. try adding 'console.log(response);'  after your alert and seeing what it prints out in firebug

Comment: Permission are ok they are user_about_meuser_likesuser_relationships,  i have adding console.log(response) but nothing also with FireBug...i don't understand...

Comment: what do you get if you replace FB.api('/me') with FB.api('/4')

Comment: Mark Z... the founder of facebook.

Comment: Ok, then you haven't granted your app access to your account as /me only returns information if you have. Look at the link I posted above about authorization http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

Comment: Ok Tommy thanks so much for all , i am trying to see the link

Comment: Ok i have try all, but  it is the same guide that i have use first time, i have all grant, but nothing the name result undefined...i don't know...if someone ha some idea...

Comment: Have you added a facebook login button to your page? As everything to me says you haven't allowed you app to read your name. Add  <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button> before you close the </body> tag and click it